# When using SQLite for offline client, better use MySQL or PostgreSQL for server?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mariadb, sqlite

I'm developing an application which uses embedded SQLite for local storage.

My application will replicate changes to internet server (via REST/HTTP).
There I can choose between MySQL/MariaDB or PostgreSQL.

My db is pretty "normal", many tables (~80), mostly with few columns (max. ~30), many M:N relationships, some of the tables carry text data (only a couple of paragraphs in length). I use some kind of compressed UUIDs as primary key because they have to be globally unique.

Being able to do case-insensitive full-text searches is almost critical.

I won't use JSON, triggers and stored functions/procedures.

From a feature and compatibility point of view (datatypes, behavior of NULL, LIKE, indexes, BLOB-handling), which db-server should I use?

Comment: Why downvote? This is not a marketing or political question expecting opinionated answers. Very concrete, named features and facts drive the decision.

Comment: To show that there's no anti-commercial opnion-based (:-)) bias, you might also wish to take a look at Zumero [here](http://zumero.com/) - it's a commerical SQLite to RDBMS server replication and synchronisation solution - it is MS SQL Server, but I've read Sink's book on the business of software and he appears to know what he's talking about - disclaimer - I have no connection with Zumero!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am literally **screaming** at my screen "**Use Postgresql!**"

SQLite is the [protégé](https://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/events/736.en.html) of PostgreSQL. That link is to a talk given by [D. Richard Hipp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._Richard_Hipp) (the inventor, and still primary developer, of SQLite) to PGCon 2014.

Furthermore, if you look at the [SQLite wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), you will find the lines:

> SQLite uses PostgreSQL as a reference platform. “What would PostgreSQL
>   do” is used to make sense of the SQL standard.[9][10] One major
>   deviation is that, with the exception of primary keys, SQLite does not
>   enforce type checking; the type of a value is dynamic and not strictly
>   constrained by the schema (although the schema will trigger a
>   conversion when storing, if such a conversion is potentially
>   reversible). SQLite strives to follow Postel's Rule.

PostgreSQL supports `CHECK` constraints whereas MySQL (astoundingly) does not! MySQL's support for Window/Analytic functions and Common Table Expressions (`CTE`s - also known as the `WITH` clause) is only in Beta - PostgreSQL has had them for years!

Overall, technically, PostgreSQL is a **vastly** superior database.

MySQL is as widespread as it is due largely to luck and good marketing - it ran natively on Windows (PostgreSQL does now also) back in the mid-nineties, and went GPL before the first internet boom.

Even if this question were not specifically about SQLite, I would unhesitatingly (99.9% of circumstances) recommend PostgreSQL over MySQL - PostgreSQL also has advanced full-text capabilities [[1](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2015/02/26/fulltext-search-with-postgresql-is-definitely-an-option-to-consider.html), [2]](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) and would also be a much better fit for this sort of functionality - out of the box (thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name) - no need for secondary tools like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/).

If you are making (ab)use of the "[well known quirk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106366/34007)" of SQLite that it "does not enforce type checking" - you will have problems when replicating - although you will have the same problems with MySQL also.

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed answer. I'm convinced and there is no doubt about the decision.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just doing another answer - no REGEXP_REPLACE in MySQL either! See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185318/34007)!

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE` is in MariaDB, along with `PCRE`.