# MySQL function: Get string/number separated by some place holder

Tags: mysql, functions

I have the following `product` table

```
| product_id    | sku   | created_at    |
|------------   |-----  |------------   |
| 145687        | abc   | 2017-08-08    |
| 22456         | xyz   | 2017-09-01    |
| 6553214       | asd   | 2017-09-05    |
```

I want to get output as `1/4/5/6/8/7` with SQL

```
SELECT someMySQLFunction(product_id) FROM product WHERE sku = 'abc';
```

How to achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: could you provide the DDL for the table, in particular I'm looking for the max length of the product_id column

Comment: For product_id: INT (11)

Comment: Some things belong in application code, not SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more simplfied approach without a stored procedure:

## PROPOSED CODE

```
SET @x = 145687;
SET @d = '-';
SET @y = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@x,'0',CONCAT('0',@d)),'1',CONCAT('1',@d)),'2',CONCAT('2',@d)),'3',CONCAT('3',@d)),'4',CONCAT('4',@d)),'5',CONCAT('5',@d)),'6',CONCAT('6',@d)),'7',CONCAT('7',@d)),'8',CONCAT('8',@d)),'9',CONCAT('9',@d));
SET @z = LEFT(@y,LENGTH(@y) - 1);
SELECT @x,@z;
```

## PROPOSED CODE EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @x = 145687;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @d = '-';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @y = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@x,'0',CONCAT('0',@d)),'1',CONCAT('1',@d)),'2',CONCAT('2',@d)),'3',CONCAT('3',@d)),'4',CONCAT('4',@d)),'5',CONCAT('5',@d)),'6',CONCAT('6',@d)),'7',CONCAT('7',@d)),'8',CONCAT('8',@d)),'9',CONCAT('9',@d));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @z = LEFT(@y,LENGTH(@y) - 1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @x,@z;
+--------+-------------+
| @x     | @z          |
+--------+-------------+
| 145687 | 1-4-5-6-8-7 |
+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Looks great!. It's even better if you can move the separator '-' to MySQL variable.

Comment: I'll change it right now, give me a minute ...

Answer (score 1):

For this solution I've opted for the 'easy' way out ... a user-defined function ...

Proposed function:

```
drop function if exists myinsert;

create function myinsert (instring char(100), inchar char(10))
returns char(100)
deterministic
begin
  declare i int;
  set i = char_length(instring);
  while i > 1 do
    set instring = insert(instring,i,0,inchar);
    set i = i - 1;
  end while;
return instring;
end;
```

- `set i = char_length(instring)` : get length of input string
- `while i/set i` : loop through values of `i` down to '2'
- `insert(instring,i,0,inchar)` : at position `i` in our string, insert `inchar`
- at this point we've stepped backwards through `instring`, inserting the `inschar` string before every character in `instring` (except for the first character)

Calling the function:

```
select myinsert(cast(product_id as char),'/') as new_string
from   product
where  sku = 'abc';

new_string
-----------
1/4/5/6/8/7

select myinsert(cast(product_id as char),'-/-') as new_string
from   product
where  sku = 'abc';

new_string
---------------------
1-/-4-/-5-/-6-/-8-/-7
```

Here are [rextester](http://rextester.com/VMM50339) and a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vCKYkjDXPQ2eJ2KAgaeHd9/6) fiddles

Comment: Your SQL is not executing correctly. Syntax Error.

Comment: Hard to guess at this point what the issue may be since both of those fiddles are working ... MySQL version? the tool/front-end you're using to create the function? perhaps try wrapping the `create function...` in a new delimiter, eg, `delimiter $$ create function ... end; $$ delimiter ;` ??

Answer (score 1):

My humblest and deepest apologies for this piece of code - it really is an embodiment of the word "hack" in its most negative connotation! :-)

To solve this conundrum I checked out MySQL's REGEXP_REPLACE capabilities, which I remembered it doesn't have! So, basically, the solution involves hardcoding the length of the integer - I found that [10 is the max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634147/470530) for INT(11) - unsigned. The good part is that even if your integer is way shorter (even only one digit - see db-fiddle), the code will still work!

So, I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tst
(
  my_val INT(11)
);

INSERT INTO tst VALUES (45323232), (82),(123433232),(123232),(12),(1),(3433);
```

And ran the SQL below (db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vCKYkjDXPQ2eJ2KAgaeHd9/5)):

```
SELECT
SUBSTR(  -- SUBSTR is to remove excess trailing slashes (/)
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
  CONCAT(  
          SUBSTR(my_val,  1, 1), '/'), -- add / after 1st character
          SUBSTR(my_val,  2, 1), '/'), -- ..          2nd ..
          SUBSTR(my_val,  3, 1), '/'),
          SUBSTR(my_val,  4, 1), '/'),
          SUBSTR(my_val,  5, 1), '/'),
          SUBSTR(my_val,  6, 1), '/'),
          SUBSTR(my_val,  7, 1), '/'),
          SUBSTR(my_val,  8, 1), '/'),
          SUBSTR(my_val,  9, 1), '/'),
          SUBSTR(my_val, 10, 1), '/'), -- ..          nth character
1,                      -- `SUBSTR` from the start of the new string
LENGTH(my_val) * 2 - 1) -- twice the original - to account for the new slashes 
                        -- and -1 to remove the last trailing slash!
AS NewStr
FROM tst;
```

Which gives the following:

```
NewStr
4/5/3/2/3/2/3/2
8/2
1/2/3/4/3/3/2/3/2
1/2/3/2/3/2
1/2
1
3/4/3/3
```

Which appears to be the correct answer. I'm afraid I can't speak to its scalability, but I suspect that it is poor!

Addendum: Based on Rolando's solution, a more elegant SQL solution can be found (db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qLdACqPdJ7TocFqCrWYNsU/1)). It has the added advantage of not hard-coding the length of the number - all the digits [0-9] are covered, no more or no less than are necessary no matter what the length of the integer.

I was unable to check out the efficiency of the solutions - I don't have a running MySQL instance (thank you db-fiddle!).

```
SELECT
LEFT
(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE(my_val, '0', '0/'),
                  '1', '1/'),
                  '2', '2/'),
                  '3', '3/'),
                  '4', '4/'),
                  '5', '5/'),
                  '6', '6/'),
                  '7', '7/'),
                  '8', '8/'),
                  '9', '9/'),
  LENGTH(my_val) * 2 - 1
)
AS NewStr
FROM tst;
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on Vérace's in-line solution:

```
set @x = '/';

select product_id, 
       substr(concat_ws(@x,
                        substr(p,1,1),
                        substr(p,2,1),
                        substr(p,3,1),
                        substr(p,4,1),
                        substr(p,5,1),
                        substr(p,6,1),
                        substr(p,7,1),
                        substr(p,8,1),
                        substr(p,9,1),
                        substr(p,10,1),
                        substr(p,11,1)
                       ),
              1, (char_length(p) * 2 - 1)) as new_id
from
(select  product_id,
         cast(product_id as char(11)) as p
 from    product
 where   sku = 'abc') dt;

product_id new_id
---------- -----------
145687     1/4/5/6/8/7
```

And a couple fiddles: [fiddle #1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5TxqmFtvAkkH12WuBJP3ja/3), [fiddle #2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=eef90e1c625f9278a5831a1ec04c6e35)

Answer (score 1):

And a somewhat convoluted, in-line solution:

```
select  dt1.product_id,
        substr(group_concat(substr(dt1.p,ndx.i,1) order by ndx.i separator '/'),
               1,char_length(dt1.p)*2-1) as new_id

 from
 (select product_id,
         cast(product_id as char(11)) as p
  from   product) dt1

 cross
 join

 (select ordinal_position as i
  from   information_schema.columns
  where  table_name = 'columns' limit 11) ndx

group by dt1.product_id
order by 1
```

- derived table `dt1` : convert `product_id` values to character strings named `p`
- derived table `ndx` : use first 11 entries from `information_schema.columns.table_name = 'columns'` to give us index values (`i`) 1..11
- `substr(dt1.p.ndx.i,1)` : cross join of `dt1` and `ndx` breaks each `product_id` character string (`p`) into separate records, 1 record for each letter in the string
- `group_concat()` : allows us to pull our individual characters back together into a single record with individual characters separated by '/'

The resulting output

```
product_id new_id
---------- ---------------
22456      2/2/4/5/6
145687     1/4/5/6/8/7
6553214    6/5/5/3/2/1/4
```

And a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5X48J5Kqt97gEn9mfLgtGa/1)